# An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I set all params, but I get exception: An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Please, help with this issue.

```
        var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount" + activateCode;
        var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

        var fromEmail = new MailAddress("******@gmail.com", "Dotnet Awesome");
        var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
        var fromEmailPassword = "******";
        string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

        string body = "<br/><br/>We are excitef to tell you Dotnet Awesome is" +
            "successfully created. Please click on the link to verify your account" +
            "<a href'" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smpt.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);//Exception here
        }
```

Comment: I tried 25 port, but it didn't bring results

Comment: Yes, I got same error with 25 port

Comment: See additional information/inner exception given by the error & post it here. Possibly you're using wrong credentials or need to enable less secure apps setting for sender GMail account.

Comment: I using correct credentials and unreliable applications are allowed in my email.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can check this one Host = "smpt.gmail.com" becz u used smpt instead of smtp